# Sort a list by namespaces

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I would like some help sorting a specific list.

Imagine the following list:

```
antennas.sequence
antennas.ports
antennas.1.power
antennas.2.power
antennas.found
radio.modulation.1.set
radio.modulation.2.set
radio.transmit
radio.frequency
```

If we applied the simple List.Sort() function it will become like this:

```
antennas.1.power
antennas.2.power
antennas.found
antennas.ports
antennas.sequence
radio.frequency
radio.modulation.1.set
radio.modulation.2.set
radio.transmit
```

But I'm looking for a sort that will respect the number of namespaces, so the items with less depth should be on top of each other. For the above example I expect the list to be sorted like this:

```
antennas.found
antennas.ports
antennas.sequence
antennas.1.power
antennas.2.power
radio.frequency
radio.transmit
radio.modulation.1.set
radio.modulation.2.set
```

Comment: One way to do this is to write your own `IComparer` implementation and pass it to [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__)

Comment: Why is `radio.transmit` before 
`radio.modulation.1.set`

Comment: The order must alphabetical but taking in consideration the number of namespaces, in this case separated by dots "."

Comment: would `antennas.1.power` come before `antennas.A.power` or after

Comment: I don't have that case, but i would assume a normal alphabetical order where number come before letters is ok.

Comment: @tvborda updated my answer

Comment: Why is "less deep" important? If you had `antennas.1` in your list it would appear out of order according to your rules.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is a good point, however I don't ask questions i just work here. Though i don't think many people would be interested in this kind of sort tbh, for the reasons you specify

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, However...

**Given Extensions**

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<string[]> RecusiveCustomOrderBy(this IOrderedEnumerable<string[]> list,int maxDepth, int depth = 1)
{
   if (depth >= maxDepth)
      return list;

   return list.ThenBy(x => x.Length <= depth ? null : x[depth])
              .ThenBy(x => x.Length)
              .RecusiveCustomOrderBy(maxDepth, depth + 1);
}

public static List<string> NamespaceOrderBy(this List<string> list)
{
   var split = list.Select(x => x.Split('.')).ToList();
   var maxDepth = split.Max(x => x.Length);

   return split.OrderBy(x => x[0])
               .ThenBy(x => x.Length)
               .RecusiveCustomOrderBy(maxDepth)
               .Select(x => string.Join(".", x))
               .ToList();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = new List<string>
   {
      "antennas.sequence",
      "antennas.ports",
      "antennas.1.power",
      "antennas.2.power",
      "antennas.found",
      "radio.modulation.1.set",
      "radio.modulation.2.set",
      "radio.transmit",
      "radio.frequency"
   };

var results = list.NamespaceOrderBy();
```

**Output**

```
antennas.found
antennas.ports
antennas.sequence
antennas.1.power
antennas.2.power
radio.frequency
radio.transmit
radio.modulation.1.set
radio.modulation.2.set
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ebnxi1)

> **Note** : It can probably do with some simple error checking